# How to correctly use __webpack_public_path__ for dynamic loading of react app?

Tags: webpack, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a webpack react app to github pages using `__webpack_public_path__`

1. I removed the `publicPath` from webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        app: ["./src/app.tsx", "./src/app.css"],
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        clean: true,
    },
```

2. I set in app.js:
   `__webpack_public_path__ = "/ewitkon/opportunity-tracker/dist/";`

When I run the application after deployment app.js is found and loaded at runtime, after deploying to github pages but everything else fails:
[image]

Note while these are fonts I have a loader for them:

```
{
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: 'fonts/',
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
```